# Tab content won't show on tab click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some tabs, but it won't show it's content when I click the tab button. The Home tab seems to work, though the content is supposed to be hidden until clicked on. The other tabs are not working still. I am using google chrome.

```js
document.getElementById("home").style.display = "inline";
var tabLinks = new Array();
var contentDivs = new Array();

function init() {

  var tabListItems = document.getElementById('tabs').childNodes;
  for (var i = 0; i < tabListItems.length; i++) {
    if (tabListItems[i].nodeName == "LI") {
      var tabLink = getFirstChildWithTagName(tabListItems[i], 'A');
      var id = getHash(tabLink.getAttribute('href'));
      tabLinks[id] = tabLink;
      contentDivs[id] = document.getElementById(id);
    }
  }

  var i = 0;

  for (var id in tabLinks) {
    tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab();
    tabLinks[id].onfocus = function() {
      this.blur()
    };
    if (i == 0) tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
    i++;
  }

  var i = 0;

  for (var id in contentDivs) {
    if (i != 0) contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    i++;
  }
}

function showTab() {
  var selectedId = getHash(this.getAttribute('href'));

  for (var id in contentDivs) {
    if (id == selectedId) {
      tabLinks[id].className = 'selected';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent';
    } else {
      tabLinks[id].className = '';
      contentDivs[id].className = 'tabContent hide';
    }
  }

  return false;
}

function getFirstChildWithTagName(element, tagName) {
  for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
    if (element.childNodes[i].nodeName == tagName) return element.childNodes[i];
  }
}

function getHash(url) {
  var hashPos = url.lastIndexOf('#');
  return url.substring(hashPos + 1);
}
```

```css
body {
  background: url('image/bg1.png');
}
nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
nav ul {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li a {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px #333;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.theme {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #111;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border: none;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
.theme:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px -6px #333;
  transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
  border: none;
}
.theme:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 #333;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  border: none;
}
.box {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  padding: 100px 200px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -6px #333;
}
div.tabContent {
  display: none;
}
hr.style {
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#ordertabs:hover {
  background: #AB1F1F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-us">

<head>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
  <nav>
    <ul id="tabs">
      <li>
        <a href="#home" style="font-weight: bold;">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#products" style="font-weight: bold;">Products</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#order" style="font-weight: bold;">Order</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#settings" style="font-weight: bold;">Settings</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <hr class="style"></hr>

  <div class="tabContent" id="home">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Welcome</h2>
      <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabContent" id="products">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Products</h2>
      <div>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="tabContent" id="order">
    <div class="box">
      <h2>Ready to fail?</h2>
      <div>
        <p></p>
        <ul id="tabs2"> <a href="#order" style="font-weight: bold;">Click to fail</a>
        </ul>
        <div class="tabContent2">
          <div class="box">
            <h2>If you are reading this, you failed.</h2>
            <div>
              <p></p>
              <p></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any reason you dont want to use bootstrap for this?, it has this pretty much mastered

Comment: @ DelightedD0D What do you mean by bootstrap?

Comment: It could be pure css tab too, http://webdesignerhut.com/create-pure-css-tabs/ and https://css-tricks.com/css3-tabs/

Comment: Checkout http://getbootstrap.com/ its a responsive library that lets you easily do a ton of really common web design stuff, like tabs. Here is an example. http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/2VmmW/ The example has custom styling applied on top of the default styles. Bootstrap will make your life a lot easier. :)

Comment: I like that. (pure css tabs) Should I change it? My goal is to also have many tabs inside other tabs. Same with the jsfiddle.

Comment: I actually like that one. I am using the css one. :)

Comment: Its not pure CSS, bootstrap has a JS file and a CSS file. It just handles everything for you, you just set up your html and let bootstrap handle all the complicated stuff. And yes, you can nest them. Let me work up a quick example. As far as "Should you change it", that depends, look through everything that bootstrap offers, if you think youll use some of the elements go for it. All of my projects are built on bootstrap, it just makes so many things really easy especially responsive design (sites that look good on mobile or desktop)

Comment: Here you go, click on "Settings" to see the nested tabs (youd have to style them to look how you need of course). You control which tab is displayed by default by adding the class "active" to the tab pane like `<div class="tab-pane fade active ....` and by adding the class active to the `li` that opens the tab like `<li class="active">`. If you remove `active` from all of them, they will start out with all content hidden. http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/2VmmW/851/

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.getAttribute is not a function

This error comes from the following line:

```
tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab();
```

You have to use the function as a reference, otherwise it will be executed as soon as the javascript engine gets to parse that line, change it as follows:

```
tabLinks[id].onclick = showTab;
```

Comment: Someone on another question told me to keep the ().

Comment: Well, it's wrong, when using a function as reference, you don't have to use the parenthesis, otherwise the function will be executed.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#home').show(); // default shows home tab
 $('#tabs a').on('click', function() { // on click of nav linnk
     var id = $(this).attr('href'); // find corresponding id
        $('.tabContent').hide(); // hide all tabContent elements
        $(id).show(); // show corresponding clicked tabContent
    });
});
```

```css
body {
  background: url('image/bg1.png');
}
nav {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}
nav ul {
  width: 50%;
  margin: auto;
}
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  float: left;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
}
li a {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333333;
  border-radius: 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  line-height: 50px;
  display: block;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
li a:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 8px -6px #333;
  color: #222222;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.theme {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  float: left;
  width: 80px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  color: #111;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border: none;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}
.theme:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 10px -6px #333;
  transition: all ease-in-out 150ms;
  border: none;
}
.theme:active {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  padding: 10px 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 #333;
  color: #000;
  text-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .6);
  border: none;
}
.box {
  font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
  padding: 100px 200px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .3);
  box-shadow: 0 10px 15px -6px #333;
}
div.tabContent {
  display: none;
}
hr.style {
  border: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}
#ordertabs:hover {
  background: #AB1F1F;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul id="tabs">
        <li>
            <a href="#home" style="font-weight: bold;">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#products" style="font-weight: bold;">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#order" style="font-weight: bold;">Order</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#settings" style="font-weight: bold;">Settings</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<hr class="style"></hr>

<div class="tabContent" id="home">
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Welcome</h2>
        <div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabContent" id="products">
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Products</h2>
        <div>
            <p></p>
            <p></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="tabContent" id="order">
    <div class="box">
        <h2>Ready to fail?</h2>
        <div>
            <p></p>
            <ul id="tabs2"> <a href="#order" style="font-weight: bold;">Click to fail</a>
            </ul>
            <div class="tabContent2">
                <div class="box">
                    <h2>If you are reading this, you failed.</h2>
                    <div>
                        <p></p>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works perfect in the snippet, but it doesn't work when I use it in my original code.

Comment: well, i think this code actually kinda replaces your js code because you're using vanilla js to do what jquery can do simply as shown in this example. does it say anything in the console.log?

Comment: I am sorry, what do you mean by counsle.log?  I do not have one, unless you are refering to this site, or chrome.

Comment: oh sorry, i misspelled. its "console.log" um its your browser debugging tool . oh but if you dont know what it is i suppose it'll be hard to ask you for any errors that show up in it hrmmm. are you still using any of your js code? or did you replace yours with mine?

Comment: I replaced it with something else. It works, so it's all good.